# What to use: Community/Site or UserGroup for our requirement

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Hey I am a newbie to liferay.

Anyway I want to provide a purchase order and compromise authorization system which should provide two types of user-groups based on who logs in.

The two users are:

1. User's related to PO(say accounts,sales department of a company)
2. Various vendors to the company(say Vendor_A,Vendor_B,Vendor_C)

On login:

1. Accounts can view various vendors depending on vendor_id & reference_PO_no
2. A particular vendor on his login should see only his details & not other vendors' detail.

I am not sure how can I achieve this; either to create a UserGroup or Community. If UserGroup/Community how does Vendor_A **not view** Vendor_B's profile. Please help if anybody has a solution or done something of this in Liferay 6.1

Software used:
Liferay portal 6.1.0 (bundled with tomcat7.0.23), MySql 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of User pages (public/private) and Sites/Communities/Organizations. The Liferay [User Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/using-liferay-portal-6-1) section [Managing Users](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/managing-users-user-groups-organizations-sites-teams-and-roles) might help you understand relation between `UserGroup` and User public/private pages.

> 1) accounts can view various vendors depending on vendor_id & reference_PO_no

You can create a portlet which displays vendor_id and reference_PO_no, and can put it on a site/Community/Organization page to which only the certain users have access. Or else you put the logic of displaying the the vendor_id and reference_PO_no in the portlet itself to certain users who have permissions.

> 2) A particular vendor on his login should see only his details & not other vendors detail.

For this you can use `User Public page` as http://liferay.com uses it. If you have an account on liferay, you can see that it has a User public page which has portlets like Wall, Friends activities etc which works only on User public pages and every user sees only the information related to his account. So in a similar way you can create a portlet for the Vendors and put it on the Vendors User (public/private) page. So that they can see only their info.

These are just some pointers to get you started. May not be the whole answer.

Comment: Hey thanks prakash for your reply will work on user pages as directed by you.